# How do I make sure the data sent to WebService using jQuery AJAX is through my site and not some attack

Tags: web-services, jquery, security, cryptojs

My Code:

```
 function HandleSignUp() {
    var CurrentURL = document.URL;
    var obj, val;
    //ajax call started
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../webservice/GetAjaxDataWebService.asmx/RegisterNewUser",
        data: "{'UserFullName': '" + $('#SignUpName').val() + "','Email': '" + $('#SignUpEmail').val() + "','Password': '" + $('#SignUpPassword').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            //msg.d contains the return value from web service call
            $.colorbox.close();

            val = eval(msg);
            obj = jQuery.parseJSON(val.d);

            UpdateLogin(obj.Email, obj.FirstName);

        }
    });
    //ajax call ended
}
```

How do I make sure the data sent to WebService using jQuery AJAX is through my site and not some attack.

I have a similar ajax call for Login, where I pass userid and password to a webservice and authenticate.

Is there a way to have a one time request-response token to make sure its a valid web service call.

Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: If you do-not have cors enabled of the server a client side script probably won't be able to send request to your service.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma I do not have Cross-Origin Resource Sharing enabled on the server. So I should not worry that someone can write an utility to call my SignUp webservice URL with bogus data and Login webservice URL with brute force attack on password for any particular userid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a lightweight MAC-ing mechanism  using a Hash Key (known only to you)

1. Before each call to the webservice feed the first `n` bytes of your message payload to the hash key and compute a hash value.
2. Make the call to your webservice, sending the hash value in an http header (I recommend the [authorization header](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/), you can create a custom header tho.
3. In your webservice, before honouring any service request, you verify the authenticity of the message by computing the hashvalue using the same data i.e. the first N bytes and compare with the hash value in the authorization header. Honour the request only if the value checks out.

There is a little processing overhead here and it assumes that the transmission is happening over a secure line, otherwise, the message could still be hijacked. But you solve the problem of bogus calls.

Comment: @Pawan you can look [here](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for something you could use, under the HMAC section

Answer (score 1):

Sessions might be the easiest solution to this problem, depending on your server framework.

After a successful login, open a session on the server and set a value; check for the session value before processing any of your other web service APIs.

Comment: I have session management in my code. But I create the session only once the user has logged in. My question above is on how to avoid bogus web service calls. From your point, I am thinking of always creating a unique session key (may be a timestamp and information from request object of the user) and pass that to my HTML page in the response, and then again getting this session payload back with the web service call. If the payload from webservice call matches my session key, I will allow the web service to go ahead. To All, let me know if this is a valid option.