# How to make sure POST data is sent from my website's form, aside from HTTP_REFERRER and using a nonce?

Tags: php, forms, session, post, security

I need to make sure a request comes from a user submitting a form on the website rather than an automated POST request.

I could use

- HTTP_REFERRER - but this is not reliable
- hidden input field with random value from session - but what's to stop a spammer from going to my form, getting the value from the hidden field, and pasting it into his "program" as part of his automated request?

Any other options?

Comment: What do you need this for? I think the token approach is the only way... but then, a spammer could also automate filling in your form directly.

Comment: Use option number two, but dynamically create it server side and put it in to a session variable, and then put it in the form as a hidden value.  When the form is submitted, check it against the session variable you created to make sure it's from your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an HMAC approach whereby you hash the first couple of bits of the POST payload using a hashing algorithm secured by a secret key known only between your php library and your backend. Store the calculated hash in the http headers, not as part of the form payload. All you need to do then is validate the data being submitted server-side by calculating the hash value using the secret key and if the hash value doesn't check out, you know it's a bogus submission. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12792698/1530938) for details.

Also, basic cookie security parameters like `HttpOnly` instructs browsers to not permit access to your set cookies via scripts in transit (VBScript, JavaScript etc) so your tokens could be a little bit more secure in transit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way: if you examine your option number #2

> *hidden input field with random value from session - but what's to stop
>   a spammer from going to my form, getting the value from the hidden
>   field, and pasting it into his "program" as part of his automated
>   request?*

what you describe is **exactly what a browser would do**. It would "go to your form", "get the value from the hidden field", and submitting it to your server.

And you can't distinguish between two identical *modi operandi*.

You can make life difficult for the spammer in a number of ways.

For example, the hidden field might be populated by a Javascript snippet; all non-JS browsers (and all your customers with JS disabled) will be bounced.

You could require a session authentication for starters; that way you'll be able to block the spammer later on by pulling his account.

Just for the laughs (**I do not recommend doing this** - clunky, risky, error-prone, you make bad enemies), you could employ psychological tactics: whatever response your system is expected to give in case of success (e.g. a spampost becoming visible), you can give also in case of failure *but only towards the same IP address that elicited the response, and only for five minutes*. Most automated spam-tools won't even check; and the majority of human "spambot tuners" will be satisfied once they see their spam appearing, and go on chuckling to their next victim. If they check later, their bots will still *appear* to work. With a bit of luck they'll believe there's a human webmaster psychotically hunting and cancelling their spam, and again they'll move on.