# Mechanism to secure a private internal web api from public access

Tags: java, web-services, security, api, web-applications

I have a java application consisting of a static HTML page and JS. In the application I have REST-like API which is called by JS from static HTML. In front of the application is a front-end proxy server, say Nginx or Apache.
the front-end server is located on server S1 and servlet container is located on server S2.

I have a page http://example.com/mycontext/page.html which includes the JS file invoking REST API located at http://example.com/mycontext/api/someresource
The front-end passes all request matching http://example.com/mycontext/ to my application.

I want to introduce another web api in my application for internal use only, i.e. this new api should be invoked and visible only by other applications in my intranet (say from server S3), not from the internet.

I want this api to be HTTP-based, WS or REST-like, and to be managed by the same servlet container, say Tomcat, in which my app is deployed.

What options do I have?

Comment: You didnt mention where your server S1 is located (external/internal), and wether it needs access to the services provided by S3.

Comment: @Perception S1 could be reached from internet and can access internal servers (S2, S3), but it does not need access to S3.

Comment: @AlexanderYastrebov, have a shared secret between the two servers/apis that are supposed to communicate. The client uses this secret to compute a MAC that will be verified by the destination service. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12792698/1530938). Your question is a possible duplicate of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My front-end passes all request matching `http://example.com/mycontext/*` to my application

The easiest answer in this case would be to change the front end *not* to pass `http://example.com/mycontext/private/*` through, and then have other servers access your internal API directly on `http://server.internal.ip:8080/mycontext/private`.

Comment: What you are asking is what I am looking for, I think. Can you please guide me a bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002283/how-to-allow-internal-mvc-web-api-from-external-site-outside-the-network Thanks.